# Colouring lines in bash variable

Tags: bash, colors

I have the following bash function which prints lines from a string variable using colour.  I want to use `wl="1,5,8"` so that lines 1, 5, and 8, are coloured in white.  How can I do this?

```
kls ()
 {
  local -r wht="$( tput bold; tput setaf 15 )"
  local -r blu="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"

  wl="1,3,5,8"

  if [[ -n "$wl" ]]; then
    printf '%s%s%s\n' "$wht" "$@" "$rst"
  else
    sed -E "s/^ *[{-].*/${blu}&${rst}/" <<< "$@"
  fi
 }
```

Here is an example string

```
str="
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9"
```

Here is the call to `kls`

```
kls "$str"
```

The output should be

```
Line 2 
Line 3  White Coloured Text
Line 4
Line 5  White Coloured Text
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8  White Coloured Text
Line 9"
```

Comment: What do you mean by `so that lines 1, 5, and 8`? The actual number line or the line where the string line matches one of the lines you want to colour?

Comment: In your example: `str="
Line 2` the string line `Line 2` is actually the line number 2 and the line number 1 is just a break line.

Comment: The variable string is composed of a multiline string, so that when printing the string, the specified lines take a specific foreground colour.

Comment: Yes I want to use a specific foreground colour when printing the line where the string matches one of the lines I want to colour.

Comment: Ok and why the line `Line 3  White Coloured Text` is matched? I think the condition here is based on the second column, For example you want to color lines `1` `5` and `8` and given your string the lines to color would be `Line 5` and `Line 8` (because the second column match the values `5` and `8`). In your case the line `1` will never be coloured because in your string that macthed line does not exist.

Comment: You are right.  I have included the `3` in `wl` otherwise it would have been a mistake to colour `Line 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` and based on second column (and assuming you always have two columns or more):

```bash
awk -v reset="$rst" -v  white="$wht" -v lines="$wl" '
BEGIN{split(lines,arrLines,",");} 
{ 
   found=0
   for(item in arrLines) {
      if (arrLines[item] == $2) { 
        found=1 ; break 
      }
   }
   if (found) { 
      print white $0 reset 
   } 
   else print $0
}' <<< "$@"
```

And based on line number:

```bash
awk -v reset="$rst" -v  white="$wht" -v lines="$wl" '
BEGIN{split(lines,arrLines,",");} 
{ 
   found=0
   for(item in arrLines) {
      if (arrLines[item] == NR) { 
        found=1 ; break 
      }
   }
   if (found) { 
      print white $0 reset 
   } 
   else print $0
}' <<< "$@"
```